# Is it safe to useMemo for JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memoization

I'm trying to do a memoize `Modal` and I have a problem here.

When I change input I dont need to re-render the Modal component.

**For example:**

`Modal.tsx` looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyledModalContent, StyledModalWrapper, AbsoluteCenter } from "../../css";

interface ModalProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
  children: React.ReactNode
};

const ModalView: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({ open, onClose, children }) => {
  console.log("modal rendered");
  
  return (
    <StyledModalWrapper style={{ textAlign: "center", display: open ? "block" : "none" }}>
      <AbsoluteCenter>
        <StyledModalContent>
          <button
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              cursor: "pointer",
              top: -10,
              right: -10,
              width: 40,
              height: 40,
              border: 'none',
              boxShadow: '0 10px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07)',
              backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
              borderRadius: 20,
              color: '#ba3c4d',
              fontSize: 18
            }}
            onClick={onClose}
          >
            X
          </button>
          {open && children}
        </StyledModalContent>
      </AbsoluteCenter>
    </StyledModalWrapper>
  );
};

export default React.memo(ModalView);
```

Here is an example of how I wrap it.

```
import React from 'react'
import Modal from './modal';

const App: React.FC<any> = (props: any) => {
  const [test, setTest] = React.useState("");
  const [openCreateChannelDialog, setOpenCreateChannelDialog] = React.useState(false);
    
  const hideCreateModalDialog = React.useCallback(() => {
    setOpenCreateChannelDialog(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" value={test} onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)} />
      <button onClick={() => setOpenCreateChannelDialog(true)}>Create channel</button>
    
      <Modal
        open={openCreateChannelDialog}
        onClose={hideCreateModalDialog}
        children={<CreateChannel onClose={hideCreateModalDialog} />}
      />
    </>
};
```

I know, `Modal` re-rendered because `children` reference created every time when `App` component re-renders (when I change an input text).

Know I'm interested, if I wrap `<CreateChannel onClose={hideCreateModalDialog} />` inside React.useMemo() hook

**For example:**

```
  const MemoizedCreateChannel = React.useMemo(() => {
    return <CreateChannel onClose={hideCreateModalDialog} />
  }, [hideCreateModalDialog]);
```

And change children props inside `Modal`

from:

```
children={<CreateChannel onClose={hideCreateModalDialog} />}
```

to

```
children={MemoizedCreateChannel}
```

It works fine, but is it safe? And it is only one solution that tried to memoize a Modal?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Memoizing JSX expressions is part of the [official `useMemo` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-memoize-calculations):

```
const Parent = ({ a }) => useMemo(() => <Child1 a={a} />, [a]); 
// This is perfectly fine; Child re-renders only, if `a` changes
```

`useMemo` memoizes individual children and computed values, given any dependencies. You can think of `memo` as a shortcut of `useMemo` for the whole component, that compares *all props*.

But `memo` has one flaw - *it doesn't work with children*:

```
const Modal = React.memo(ModalView);

// React.memo won't prevent any re-renders here
<Modal>
  <CreateChannel />
</Modal>
```

`children` are part of the props. And `React.createElement` always creates a new immutable object reference ([REPL](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAggBwTAvDAFASlQPhgHgGEQBbBHfAEwEsA3HACQFMAbFkfAehvq-LJwAoQaEix-yNACUmAQ2BQAdCSYkQ6dAG9gAC2otKAJyZgAvthR5d-oycxA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=)). So each time `memo` compares props, it will determine that `children` reference has changed, if not a primitive.

To prevent this, you can either use `useMemo` in parent `App` to memoize `children` (which you already did). Or define a [custom comparison function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) for `memo`, so `Modal` component now becomes responsible for performance optimization itself. [`react-fast-compare`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-fast-compare) is a handy library to avoid boiler plate for `areEqual`.

Answer (score -2):

Is it safe? Yes. At the end of the day the JSX is just converted into a JSON object, which is totally fine to memoize.

That said, I think it is stylistically a bit weird to do this, and I could foresee it leading to unexpected bugs in the future if things need to change and you don't think it through fully.

Comment: `At the end of the day the JSX is just converted into a JSON object` Good news for me, thanks! Where I can read more details?


I agree with you, it is a very very strange, but how can I do otherwise?

I dont think I will have a bug in the future for the specific case, it is a just a Modal and I want to show it when open is equal to true...

Comment: Honestly it seems to me like you are just being a bit over-aggressive with trying to prevent a component from rerendering. That said, have you tried `React.memo`ing the `CreateChannel` component?

Comment: @TazoLeladze I know I'm a bit late, but you can just look at `console.log(React.createElement('div', { className: "world" }));` for example.