# Why does useWindowDimensions cause this component to remount all children on resize?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

As the title says, this component works perfectly until I add useWindowDimensions(). After that, all children remount (and call my database again) whenever the screen size changes.

```
export const GroupScreen = (props) => {
  const user = getAuth().currentUser;
  const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const isLargeScreen = width >= 768;
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453845/is-it-safe-to-usememo-for-jsx
  const Cards = () =>
    useMemo(
      () => (
        <CardsView
          groupId={props.route.params.groupId}
          groupName={props.route.params.name}
        />
      ),
      [props.route.params.groupId, props.route.params.name]
    );
  const Chat = () =>
    useMemo(
      () => <ChatScreen groupId={props.route.params.groupId} />,
      [props.route.params.groupId]
    );

  if (isLargeScreen)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1.5, padding: 10 }}>
          <Cards />
        </View>
        <Chat />
      </View>
    );
  else
    return (
      <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Cards"
          component={Cards}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons
                name="cards"
                size={18}
                color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Chat"
          component={Chat}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
              <Ionicons
                name="ios-chatbubble"
                size={18}
                color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"}
              />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    );
};
```

Am I abusing React Hooks somehow?

~~This is a seemingly simple question but StackOverflow is requiring me to fill this post with useless words. What happened to the need for concise posts?~~

Comment: Without checking, under the hood i think useWindowDimensions is a useEffect with a window listener or equivalent. That updates your width and height and because your isLargeScreen is a free floating variable, it rerenders everything. What you wanna do is useMemo on your user getAuth() line to avoid recalling your db whenever size changes and/or useEffect to update your isLargeScreen variable and make it a useState variable. The latter should fix rerendering every time, and the former should fix db calls as extra safety

Comment: Hey, you should consider replacing useMemo with useCallback in your Code. [Here](https://procoders.tech/blog/difference-between-usememo-and-usecallback/#:~:text=UseCallback%20is%20used%20to%20optimize,call%20them%20on%20every%20render.) is further explanation

Comment: @MaximilianDietel I switched to useCallback and now it only calls the database again when the isLargeScreen if statement flips. Not quite perfect, but def better than before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `isLargeScreen` is causing the whole component to rerender because every time width changes, it has to recalculate that variable.

What you wanna do is make `isLargeScreen` a state, and have a useEffect to update that with your logic and add width as a dependency.

```
const [isLargeScreen, setIsLargeScreen] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(()=>{
  if (width >= 768) setIsLargeScreen(true);
  return;
},[width]);
```

If that doesn’t work, also useMemo on your getAuth() call.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, but this change doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Even after you useMemo on the getAuth() as well?