# Most efficient way to share props between siblings in react

Tags: reactjs

```js
export default function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState("");

    return (
        <>
            <main>
                <Component_A state={state} setState={setState}/>
                <Component_B />
            </main>

            <Component_C />

            <Component_D state={state} />
        </>
    );
}
```

I want to share the state between Component_A and Component_D and this is the way I'm doing it. However, when the state is changed it causes a re-render of the whole App since the state is maintained there. What would be the most efficient way to maintain state between Component_A and Component_B?

EDIT: Another way to ask this question is: How to prevent components from re-rendering if their props are not changing?

Comment: `useContext` is not an option, since you want to avoid rerenders (it will cause all its children to rerender at every `value` prop change). For that case you will have to make use a state management library. You can go from `jotai` for simple atoms, or `Zustand` for something a bit more complex or `Redux Toolkit` for larger states.

Comment: Will using those not cause a re-render of Component_B and Component_C?

Comment: Hey there! Just wanted to drop a friendly suggestion. You can give the `contextAPI` a try, but keep in mind that it will still cause a re-render for all the children components under the context provider. However, don't worry about your implementation! Another option you can consider is to use the **useMemo** hook. Check out this [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423476/14953535) for more information. Hope this helps!

Comment: I personally don't like `contextAPI`. `Zustand` or `jotai` are super simple to implement and subscriptions don't cause rerender to components that are not subscribed to that selector.

Comment: Questions asking about "the best way" are subjective and not a good fit for stackoverflow. There are different approaches with different benefits and shortcomings. No single answer will be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. Memoization.
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo. Although it's an optimization which is not necessary unless required and my current code is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

**As looks like you are trying to do the props drill in your application, due to this your component re-renders.**

What would be the most efficient way to maintain state between Component_A and Component_B?
You should learn to implement using `useContext` or `Redux` in react and use state data accordingly which need to affect the DOM.

It is really very big things to discuss, here are the things please read on google:-

**1. React Fiber and Reconciliation**

**2. Use of `useContext` in the proper way**

**3. Use of redux `useSelector` proper way.**

If you learn this three things then you start loving React.

Comment: I was talking about Component_B and Component_C which were re-rendering because of the state change of App

Comment: That was happing due to props drilling, those props changing

Comment: There are no props being sent to Component_B and Component_C. They were getting re-rendered due to the state of their parent (App) being changed.